# If radio box is checked go to link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing a quote website and i want if a user want to see most recent quotes to press the radio button and the page will display most recent quotes . I can not figure it out how to make the radio box to send to a certain page.

```
<input type="radio" name="order" id="noi" value="noi">
<label for="noi">Most Recent</label>
<input type="radio" name="order" id="vechi" value="vechi" >
<label for="vechi">Most Old</label>
<input type="radio" name="order" id="aprec" value="aprec" >
<label for="aprec">Most Liked</label>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryBs6/42/)

I want to make something like [this](http://radiobuttons.50webs.com/) but without be need to press the submit button, but when radio box is checked be sent automaticaly to a link. 
Don`t know if this is right or not but i have seen to other websites this kind of sort.

Is this possible without javascript or jquery?

Comment: Not possible without js, **BUT** you can create a pseudo radio button using the a tag and css, that acts like you desire.

Comment: and how should i resolve this?

Comment: nope u have to use jquery !

Comment: by triggering an jquery event on check of a checkbox

Comment: @CodingAnt A checkbox isn't a radio button ;)

Comment: Why can`t this radio act like "text" and be something like <a href="google.com"><input type="radio" value="google"></a> ?

Comment: I am starting to believe that you are the one who's disabling javascript and making our work difficult :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ryBs6/47/ - Update jsfiddle

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click",function(){window.open($(this).attr("href"))})
```

anyway this would work , because if i right click and open link in new tab it works , but single click doesnt work, i dont know if this is disabled for security reasons or what !

http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/6vCdX/

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><input type="radio" name="order" id="noi"  value="noi"></a>
    <label for="noi">Most Recent</label>
```

Comment: this is javascript, author wanted it without.

Comment: I would say this is jquery :)

Comment: exactly what was i thinking Thank you!

Comment: but how can i make open in same page not in other tab

Comment: use  window.open(url, "_self")

Comment: I did not know if is it possible without js or jquery. But is ok this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY don't want to use Javascript, try wrapping the input and the label in an anchor

```
<a href="http://google.com"><input type="radio" /></a>
```

If you want to use some javascript, do

```
<input onclick="window.open('http://google.com');" />
```

Or if you don't want to use the onclick attribute, use ProllyGeek's answer (I like his answer the best):

```
$("input[type='radio']").on("click",function(){window.open($(this).attr("href"))})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="radio" data-href='https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9l5FU5L8C6KL8QfOz4GABA' name="order" id="noi" value="noi">
    <label for="noi">Most Recent</label>
     <input type="radio" data-href='https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9l5FU5L8C6KL8QfOz4GABA' name="order" id="vechi" value="vechi" >
    <label for="vechi">Most Old</label>
    <input type="radio" data-href='https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=9l5FU5L8C6KL8QfOz4GABA' name="order" id="aprec" value="aprec" >
    <label for="aprec">Most Liked</label>
```

This should be your html

```
$('input[type='radio']').click(function()
                 {

                 window.location=$(this).attr('data-href')
                 });
```

You js here

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsbin.com/burak/1/)</kbd>**

### Now without javascript or jquery

---

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><input type="radio" name="order" id="vechi" value="vechi" ></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <script>
    $(function(){
        $("input").change(function() {
           if(this.checked) {
             window.location = this.value;
          }
      });
    });
    </script>


    <input type="radio" name="order" id="noi" value="http://stackoverflow.com">
    <label for="noi">Most Recent</label>
    <input type="radio" name="order" id="vechi" value="http://stackoverflow.com" >
    <label for="vechi">Most Old</label>
    <input type="radio" name="order" id="aprec" value="http://stackoverflow.com" >
    <label for="aprec">Most Liked</label>
```

<kbd>[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/codingantGit/6z54F/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Without jquery:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(item){
    item.addEventListener('change', function(e){;
        location.href = e.srcElement.value; // Redirect to value
    });
});
```